# Web scraping with multiple url

Tags: javascript, discord.js, cheerio

i need to do some web scraping with multiple url for my discord bot (i need to get the first a href inside of a h3 element from multiple url and send it with the bot), i managed to make it work only for one url

```
const uri='some url'
const uri2='some url2'
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');
var a_href 
//repeat this for every 2 hours
setInterval(async function run() {
    const options = {
    uri,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    transform: (body) => {
    return cheerio.load(body);
}}
try{
    const $ = await rp(options);
    //get the first href from a h3 element
    $('.table h3 > a').attr('href')

    $(".table").each(function(){
    a_href = $(this).find('h3 > a').attr('href');

});

    }catch(e){
     console.log(e);
}}, 7100000);

client.on('ready', () => {
    var generalChannel = 
    client.channels.get("593113450398613537") 
    setInterval (function () {
    generalChannel.send(a_href)  
  }, 7200000); 
})
```

Comment: You can't redefine variable `uri` and even can't change value of `const`. Make it as array. `['uri1', 'uri2']`.

Comment: yeah, sorry i forgot to add a "2" at the end of the second uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use two Intervals. Loop through your urls.

```
const urls = ['some url','some url2']
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const rp = require('request-promise');

client.on('ready', () => {
    let generalChannel = client.channels.get("593113450398613537")

    //repeat this for every 2 hours
    setInterval (function () {
        for(let url of urls) {
            let a_href = ''

            try {
                const $ = await rp({
                    url,
                    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
                    transform: (body) => cheerio.load(body)
                });

                //get the first href from a h3 element
                a_href = $('.table h3 > a').attr('href')
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

            generalChannel.send(a_href)
        }
    }, 7200000);
})
```

Comment: i receive ReferenceError: options is not defined

Comment: No idea why but you can pass that diretly to function (see my latest edit).

Comment: instead of url i receive 0 and 1 in the loop any fix for that?

Comment: oh sorry, use instead of `in` operator, the `of`operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop or iterator to go through an array of urls. It appears you are actually overriding your uri constant.

You might have luck passing your url into an array so:

```
const urls = ['some_url1', 'some_url2']
```

And then use a for loop or iterator to go through your array.